# Liferay 6.2 CE GA2 - How can a portlet preserve its view state while Preferences is triggered from another portlet within the same page?

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay-6, portlet

I have 2 custom portlets within a page (A and B portlets), and a defined custom Role to edit Preferences from A only.

An user with this custom Role logs in, the page is loaded in view mode (`p_p_mode=view`) and then both portlets are visible for the user.

The problem arises when the user presses on the Preferences button from A portlet, `p_p_mode=edit` is now triggered, and this results with: A portlet visible in edit mode and B portlet raising a "You do not have the roles required to access this portlet." message.

I've tried adding `<add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource>` within B portlet's `<portlet>` tag definition within `liferay-portlet.xml`, and still the same problem.

I would like to note also that both portlets are defined within the same `portlet.xml` and `liferay-portlet.xml`.

Thanks a lot in advance!

---

**Edit 1** - Add `portlet.xml` and `liferay-portlet.xml` contents

`portlet.xml`:

```
<portlet-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>custom-portlet-a</portlet-name>
        <display-name>Custom Portlet A</display-name>
        <portlet-class>com.test.liferay.portlet.CustomPortletA</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>view-jsp</name>
            <value>/html/custom-portlet-a.jsp</value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <name>edit-jsp</name>
            <value>/html/custom-portlet-a-preferences.jsp</value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <name>config-template</name>
            <value>/html/custom-portlet-a-config.jsp</value>
        </init-param>
        <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>config</portlet-mode>
            <portlet-mode>edit</portlet-mode>
            <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
            <window-state>normal</window-state>
        </supports>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>Custom Portlet A</title>
            <short-title>Custom Portlet A</short-title>
            <keywords>something</keywords>
        </portlet-info>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
    </portlet>

    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>custom-portlet-b</portlet-name>
        <display-name>Custom Portlet B</display-name>
        <init-param>
            <name>view-jsp</name>
            <value>/html/custom-portlet-b.jsp</value>
        </init-param>
        <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>edit</portlet-mode>
            <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>                        
            <window-state>normal</window-state>          
        </supports>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>Custom Porlet B</title>
            <short-title>Custom Porlet B</short-title>
            <keywords>something</keywords>
        </portlet-info>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
    </portlet>

</portlet-app>
```

`liferay-portlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE liferay-portlet-app PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Portlet Application 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_2_0.dtd">
<liferay-portlet-app>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>custom-portlet-a</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <configuration-action-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.DefaultConfigurationAction</configuration-action-class>
        <instanceable>false</instanceable>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
    </portlet>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>custom-portlet-b</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <instanceable>false</instanceable>
        <add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource>
    </portlet>

    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        <role-link>Administrator</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
        <role-link>Guest</role-link>
    </role-mapper>
    <role-mapper>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        <role-link>Power User</role-link>
    </role-mapper>

</liferay-portlet-app>
```

Comment: Could you show your portlet.xml?

Comment: Added both portlet.xml and liferay-portlet.xml files, check the Edit 1 section.

Comment: Both of your portlets seems to have same `security-role-ref`-s. And you saying that - *You do not have the roles required to access this portlet.* message is shown in one of them when you trying to edit the other, right?

Comment: Yes, that message appears for porlet B ONLY when p_p_mode=edit is triggered (both manually changing it on the URL or by pressing on 'Preferences' button from portlet a).